# Почему удаляется libgdx игра, если я скачиваю вторую?

Tags: android, libgdx

У меня на телефоне есть одна игра, которую сам сделал под названием "Гонки"
Когда скачиваю втору, другую ,но сделанную на libgdx игру под названием "Герои", то "Гонки" почему-то удаляются. Что делать? Мне нужны обе игры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое может произойти если у обеих игр один и тот же пакет (package name). Проверьте в проектах игр какой он у вас и поменйте так, чтобы у каждой игры он был свой. Пакет используется как уникальный идентификатор приложения как на телефоне так и в PlayMarket, т.е., например, вы не сможете также и выложить в него 2 игры с одинаковым `package name`